# Is there a way to organise a CSV file with outward codes into a map showing data in different areas

Tags: dictionary, gis, qgis

I have a CSV file full of data showing battery storage units in the UK. The data has a column full of outward postcodes (eg. SW17, PL19) and I'm wanting to organise this into a map that shows the amount of battery storage units in each area (such as Local Authority Districts). I basically just want to show a comprehensive view of the amount of storage in each areas so we can see in demand areas. Can anyone suggest any ideas?

I have organised the data so that each has an outward postcode. However, I'm not sure how I can organise this in QGIS so that I can create a aesthetically pleasing map showing the amount of storage in different areas